# Difference between Textbox and RichTextbox wpf?

Tags: wpf, textbox, richtextbox

Textbox and RichTextbox are look like same.But don't know the difference.Please tell me anyone, When i have to use TextBox and RichTextbox as well in wpf.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779.aspx) overview of the differences between a TextBox and a RichTextBox.

From above Link:

> Both RichTextBox and TextBox allow users to edit text, however, the two controls are used in different scenarios. A RichTextBox is a better choice when it is necessary for the user to edit formatted text, images, tables, or other rich content. For example, editing a document, article, or blog that requires formatting, images, etc is best accomplished using a RichTextBox. A TextBox requires less system resources then a RichTextBox and it is ideal when only plain text needs to be edited (i.e. usage in forms).

Answer (score 1):

A **RichTextBox** mainly used if you want more control  over styling the text color, type, font, alignment ect. So anything you can do in Microsoft Word, you can do with a RichTextBox. 
It can be used to save or display .rtf files with ease.

A **Textbox** is basically used to display or get one line input.  You can have a multi-line TextBox which is used mainly to display or get more than one one-liner and keeps you from having to
 manage multiple TextBox's.   Also keeps your UI a little more tidy.

So basically the main difference is in styling. If you just want something plain and simple, use TextBox.  If you want something fancy, eg styles, colors use a RichTextBox.

Have a look at this:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/a06ab05a-fbde-47ef-89c5-a7a57f32ffd3

Answer (score 1):

A lot has been said about the differences in the controls' usage scenario.

An important *technical* difference is that TextBox supports DataBinding, RichTextBox does not, which makes it a bit nasty to use in an MVVM application. If you want a RichTextBox with DataBinding facilities, check out the [extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.